# Is Google BigQuery API usable in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-bigquery

I was reading this documentation but I'm not sure how to integrate the client library to a Unity project: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-csharp

I would like to know if it's possible to use Google BigQuery API in Unity.

Thanks

Comment: You will probably have to write your own through the [REST interface](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/client-libraries-explained#resthttp_apis) as the [supported platforms](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client) do not include .NET 2.0 (which is Unity's underlying platform).